# Angular: Is it possible to put opening and closing tags in separate components?

Tags: angular

Working on an app with several views that each have a complex header and footer (which are identical for all the views). I would like to put the header and footer html code in their own components but the compiler complains ("Unexpected closing tag div"). Is there a way to have the compiler ignore these errors?

the code looks like this (only much more complex):

```
<div class="class1">
<div class="class2">

//main body of the code here

</div>
</div>
```

so i'd like to put the top 2 lines of code in one component and the bottom 2 lines in a separate one so the code looks like this:

```
<app-header>
//main body of the code here
<app-footer>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: No you can’t do this really. And I’m curious as to why you would anyway. I really can’t think of a scenario where this makes sense. Obviously you can nest components to your hearts content..?

Comment: What you are looking for is something like content projection via `ng-content`. Here's some examples https://alligator.io/angular/content-projection-angular/ and https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ng-content/ You still will have to close the tags, but it does what you need.

Comment: The reason I want to do is is that the top section has about 20 lines of code and the bottom section has about 20 lines of code and I am currently copy-pasting all that code dozens of times through-out my app. It would be nice to put it all into a single component.

Comment: @Rick, in that case you're not taking advantages of component architecture, you could easily resolve this by having a `header` component and a `footer` component then you can do something like this in your `app.component`: `<header/> <router-outlet></router-outlet> <footer/>`

Comment: @penleychan: I think you missed the main problem. My header component only has opening div tags and no closing tags, and the footer has all the closing tags. It would work perfectly except the compiler complains and errors out.

Comment: @Rick, then i would suggest you take a look at my first comment, using `ng-content`

Comment: @ConnorsFan, lol sorry but that doesn't help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try

**Method 1**

make a component for the top lines(app-header) and the component for the bottom lines(app-footer) then in 
all your views add:

```
<app-header></app-header>
-- your divs here
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

**Method2**

Make one component(ex: app-main-view) for the top lines and bottom lines like:

```
<div class="header1">
<div class="header2">

<ng-content></ng-content>

<div class="footer 1">
<div class="footer 2">
```

then in all views add

```
<app-main-view>
your divs here
</app-main-view>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. The method 1 doesn't help as that is what I attempted but it crashes the compiler as the opening div tags are all in app-header and all the closing div tags are in app-footer. I'll give method 2 a try

Comment: The idea of using 'ng-content' helped me out also. Thank you, @Eid Morsy

Answer (score 3):

Angular is different in a few ways than other frameworks out there that simply "include" chunks of HTML in your page as if they were copy/pasted there. You are getting the error `Unexpected closing div tag` because each component should have valid HTML, meaning that there cannot be any unclosed tags in any given Angular component. Angular is actually pretty strict in how it validates your HTML. Other frameworks, such as Wordpress which uses PHP, may be different where you can trust that a server is going to concatenate all of the HTML together before it's served.

Angular is different in that its "compiler" validates the structure of each component as a self-contained unit or..."component"...that can be rendered independently of other components. Therefore, each Angular component should start and terminate within the scope of a component. Here is one way you may achieve your code. There are some exceptions to this, such as when you want to render contents directly between the opening and closing HTML tag of your Angular component, but that's probably not what you need to do here.

Here are some suggested approaches.

#### 1. If you have Routing (HIGHLY RECOMMENDED)

(app.component.html)

```
<!-- Each "view" will have this header appended to the top -->
<app-header></app-header>

<!-- the main contents of each "view" is rendered here depending on your route (URL) in the address bar -->
<router-routlet></router-outlet> 

<!-- Each "view" will have this header appended to the bottom -->
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

You could then navigate to your various components via the URL such as:
`localhost:4200/view-1` or `localhost:4200/view-2`. And there are many other benefits of using this approach. But the header and footer remain wrapped around all of the content that gets rendered within the `<router-outlet>` component and you only had to define each of those tags in one place.
[Learn more about routing with Angular 2+](https://angular.io/guide/router)

A more involved approach is to simply include the `app-header` and `app-footer` tags into each component. This approach violates the DRY (don't repeat yourself) principle, IMHO.

#### 2. If you want to include the header / footer into *each* component:

```
<!-- some.component.html -->
<app-header></app-header>
<!-- "view" 1 contents -->
<app-footer></app-footer>

<!-- some-other.component.html -->
<app-header></app-header>
<!-- "view" 2 contents -->
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

#### 3. If you're trying to apply a common layout structure to your views:

If all of your pages are trying to use a common structure (such as with layout frameworks such as bootstrap) where you want everything in the page to fall under a particular div structure with given classes, you can simply modify approach #1 and use a combination of the main `app.component.html` and [Angular Routing](https://angular.io/guide/router) to wrap each view in common beginning and ending tags. The most common and efficient way to do this in Angular 2+ is to use routing to control the components that get rendered between the opening and closing tags. As far as any additional styling of `class1` and `class2` go, you can either modify their styling in app.component.css or styles.css (or whatever stylesheet flavor you are using).

(app.component.html)

```
<div class='class1'>
  <div class='class2'>

    <!-- The magic to render your different views happens here -->
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>

  </div>
</div>
```

Here's an actual example from a game engine I'm working on. It uses Angular Material to apply a basic sidebar / main content structure, but you can see how I've got some structural elements setup wrapping my `<router-outlet>`, which is responsible for then rendering the various views in my app.

```
<mat-drawer-container class="class1">
  <mat-drawer mode="side" position='end'>
    <app-controls></app-controls>
  </mat-drawer>
  <mat-drawer-content class='class2>
    <app-menu></app-menu>
    <!-- views are rendered here -->
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </mat-drawer-content>
</mat-drawer-container>
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: the first part of your post made a lot of sense. but then your suggestions don't seem to help me as I still have opening tags in the header and closing tags in the footer, so it won't compile. thanks though

Comment: @Rick - I've updated my answer with a third option that you might consider. Good luck!

Comment: thanks but I was able to get it to work using <ng-content></ng-content> tag. See Method 2 of Eid Morsy response.

Answer (score -1):

No there is no way to bypass the Div error shown. You have to strictly follow the syntax. the way u can use is

```
<app-header></app-header>
-- your divs and code here
<app-footer></app-footer>
```